# Deserialize EML to MailMessage in .NET/C#

Tags: c#, serialization, mailmessage, eml

I've found this pretty way ([Elegant way to serialize a MailMessage object in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745392/elegant-way-to-serialize-a-mailmessage-object-in-net)) to serialize a MailMessage to a EML-String. But now I also need the way backwards - I want to deserialize the EML-String to a MailMessage.

I've already tried a view things but have not found the solution yet. Can someone help me please?

Thank You!

Regards
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use a library such as my [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) library which can parse any MIME formatted stream or file.